# Paracol package with footnotes and hyperref leads to invalid links

Tags: hyperref, footnotes, paracol

I want to use the `paracol` package to have two-column layouts. Everything works great with the exception of footnote hyperlinks. Those seem to be not working from inside paracol environments.

See this minimal example:

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{paracol}
\usepackage{hyperref}

\footnotelayout{m}

\begin{document}
    \begin{paracol}{2}
        This is a text with a footnote on the first page.\footnote{My first footnote.}
        \switchcolumn
        Another column without footnote.
    \end{paracol}
    \pagebreak
    \begin{paracol}{2}
        Next page with columns.
        \switchcolumn
        Just another column.
    \end{paracol}
    \pagebreak

    Now I have a text outside of paracol with a footnote.\footnote{Outside of paracol.}
    \begin{paracol}{2}
         Back in paracol another column.
        \switchcolumn
         This time the second column has the footnote.\footnote{Footnote in paracol.}
    \end{paracol}
\end{document}
```

The hyperlink for the footnote outside of the paracol environment is working, but the others are not.

In the log I get the messages:

```
pdfTeX warning (dest): name{Hfootnote.3} has been referenced but does not exi
st, replaced by a fixed one

pdfTeX warning (dest): name{Hfootnote.1} has been referenced but does not exist
, replaced by a fixed one
```

Is this unsupported or am I missing something?
Edit: the paracol version is 2018/12/31 v1.35.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I suspect this combination has never been tested/debugged.  It appears the anchors were never added to the footnotes.  You can add them manually using the following.  This would have generated a *duplicate anchor" message if the anchors had existed previously.

It might be possible to make a full fix, but it would require digging into the interstices of both paracol and hyperref.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{hyperref}
\usepackage{paracol}
\footnotelayout{m}

\newcommand{\PcolFoot}{\raisebox{\ht\strutbox}{\hypertarget{Hfootnote.\theHfootnote}{}}}

\begin{document}
    \begin{paracol}{2}
        This is a text with a footnote on the first page.\footnote{\PcolFoot My first footnote.}
        \switchcolumn
        Another column without footnote.
    \end{paracol}
    \pagebreak
    \begin{paracol}{2}
        Next page with columns.
        \switchcolumn
        Just another column.
    \end{paracol}
    \pagebreak

    Now I have a text outside of paracol with a footnote.\footnote{Outside of paracol.}
    \begin{paracol}{2}
         Back in paracol another column.
        \switchcolumn
         This time the second column has the footnote.\footnote{\PcolFoot Footnote in paracol.}
    \end{paracol}
\end{document}
```